# If $\{M_\alpha\}$ is a set of irreducible modules, then is $\prod M_\alpha$ completely reducible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, noncommutative-algebra, direct-product

I am studying from Jacobson's *Basic Algebra II* (2nd edition), and I am stuck on Exercise 6 of $\S$3.5 (page 122):

> **Exercise 3.5.6.** *Suppose $\{ M_\alpha \}$ is a set of irreducible modules. Is $\prod M_\alpha$ completely reducible?*

If $\{ M_\alpha \}$ is a finite collection of irreducible modules, then $\prod M_\alpha = \bigoplus M_\alpha$, so it is completely reducible.

On the other hand, if $\{ M_\alpha \}$ is an infinite collection of irreducible modules, then I guess that $\prod M_\alpha$ is not completely reducible, since $\bigoplus M_\alpha \subsetneq \prod M_\alpha$. However, I am not able to give a clear argument for why $\prod M_\alpha$ is not completely reducible.

Jacobson has earlier proved the following characterisation of completely reducible modules (on page 121):

> **Theorem 3.10.** *The following conditions in a module $M$ are equivalent:*
>
> 1. *$M = \sum M_\alpha$, where the $M_\alpha$ are irreducible.*
> 2. *$M$ is completely reducible.*
> 3. *The lattice $L(M)$ of submodules of $M$ is complemented, that is, for every submodule $N$ of $M$ there exists a submodule $N'$ of $M$ such that $M = N \oplus N'$.*

Perhaps one can show that for $N = \bigoplus M_\alpha$ there does not exist any submodule $N'$ of $\prod M_\alpha$ such that $N \oplus N' = M$, so that $(3)$ fails to hold? But, I'm not sure how to go about this.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over the ring $\mathbb{Z}$, consider the product $\prod_p\mathbb{Z}/(p)$ where $p$ ranges over all the primes.  Then each $\mathbb{Z}/(p)$ is irreducible, but the product is not completely reducible since a completely reducible $\mathbb{Z}$-module is torsion but the element of the product which is $1$ on all coordinates is not torsion.

Note, though, that an infinite product of irreducible modules *may* be completely reducible.  For instance, over a field, every module is completely reducible.

Comment: Thank you, this clears it up for me! "... a completely reducible $\Bbb{Z}$-module is torsion" is something I should have recognised sooner.